# Located a input field by Xpath method

Tags: selenium

I have a question : There is a Login page (http://mail.126.com).

[image]

We have two input fields(Username and Password). I want to locate those two input fields by `x-path` method in selenium. Could someone help me with the solution.

Edit : Sharing the inspect element screen for elements :

[image]

Comment: It would help if you post the HTML code here and also what have you tried?
If you are using Firefox browser you can use Firepath add-on.

Comment: @Haxor : I hope the inspect element screen could help :)

Answer (score 0):

xpath - > `//input[@name='email']`